# How to correctly export aggregated javascript classes

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc, es6-class, javascript-intellisense

I'm using VSCode 1.41.1 (November 2019 release). I have some JavaScript classes in a folder like so:

**a.js**

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.m = 2;
    }
}

export default A;
```

**b.js**

```
class B {
    constructor() {
        this.n = 4;
    }
}

export default B;
```

I am trying to gather them into a single library so that I can do something like Lib.A to refer to the A class.

My current method is this:

**lib.js**

```
import A from './a';
import B from './b';

class Lib {};

Lib.A = A;
Lib.B = B;

export default Lib;
```

I then would like to use the Lib class in an external app. I have this file:

**app.js**

```
import Lib from './lib';

/**
 * @param {Lib.A} a
 * @param {Lib.B} b
 */
function foo(a, b) {
}
```

However, when I mouse over the params `a` or `b`, the tool tips say `(parameter) a: typeof A` and `(parameter) b: typeof B`, respectively, and not `(parameter) a: A` and `(parameter) b: B` like I would expect. Additionally, the auto-completion when I do `a.` shows the A class properties, and not an instance of A (with the `m` member), just like the tool tips imply.

I have a more complex project whose import/export code hasn't changed, and this behavior didn't exist in it a few months ago. It seems like a VSCode update perhaps?

Or maybe I'm not combining the A and B classes or exporting the Lib class correctly? Or maybe the JSDoc that I'm using has changed how param typing is declared?

Thank you for any help you can give.

Edit:
I've also tried for the Lib export:

```
const Lib = {
    A,
    B
};
```

But this makes the VSCode Intellisense for the foo function parameters just show `any` as their type.

Also, I see that just doing:

```
const a = new Lib.A();
```

The intellisense does correctly make the variable `a` as a type `A`. So perhaps I'm just doing the JSDoc `@param` declaration wrong?

Comment: Create an index where you reexport all the exported ones like `export { default as A } from 'a;`

Comment: How are you using your function foo ? `foo(Lib.A, Lib.B)` returns this kind of tooltip.

Comment: @quirimmo, I believe this wouldn't export A as part of the default export of the Lib class, but just export A as one of the named exports. I'm hoping to have a default export of the Lib object with A and B as members.

Comment: @karkael I'm hoping to use my function like `foo(new Lib.A(), new Lib.B());`, where the parameters are instantiations of Lib.A and Lib.B, not the classes themselves.